# I2C will timeout when running but not when debugging

Tags: c, embedded, i2c

im trying to create code that works with external at24c32n eeprom memory through I2C bus. I created this function in i2c library that i also created:

```
uint8_t eeprom_write_data(uint8_t *inputString[16])
{
   uint16_t eeAddr = 0;
   uint8_t err = 0;
   eeAddr = next_unused_addr(); //reads 0xFFF eeprom address to get nr of inputs in eeprom
   if(eeAddr == TWI_ERROR_START || eeAddr == TWI_ERROR_RSTART)
   {
      return eeAddr;
   }
   err = EEPROM_write_handler(eeAddr, inputString, sizeof(inputString)/sizeof(inputString[0])); //writes to eeprom
   if(err == TWI_OK)
   {
      err = increment_eeprom_counter(eeAddr); //increments the number of inputs in eeprom on 0xFFF address
   }
   return err;
}
```

The problem really is in "increment_eeprom_counter". To be specific i can put whatever function i want there (even already used and tested like EEPROM_write_handler) and I2C will timeout on sending start condition. The weird thing is when i debug the code and step over it, it runs as expected. However i must "step in" the function to the library to do so. If i step over in main it will timeout again. Im at total loss here. Is there anyone who knows better than me? Thank you

Comment: Did you read the data sheet? Are you delaying between writes?

Comment: Hmm... this could be it. I did read the datasheet but totally forgot about it. Thank you

Comment: It was it! Kinda dumb error from my side. Thank you so much @stark!